# Can anyone recommend a good rental company near San Francisco?

Tags: rental, recommendations, location-recording

I've never rented before, so I'd like to know if anyone has had good experiences in the bay area.  I'd like to rent a few mics and field recorders and mixers to get some hands-on experience with a wide variety of equipment.  Field and location recording, sound effects etc is all new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VER (Video Equipment Rentals) has a location in South San Francisco.

I highly recommend this company.

Comment: Talked to a rep.. very helpfull.  I think I'll stop shopping around and go with these guys when the time comes.  Actually going to end up renting video stuff from them first.  

Comment: @aross001 Cool. Glad I could help! Good luck!